# concatenate numpy string array along an axis?

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have a 2-d numpy array of strings. Is there a way to concatenate the strings in each row and then join the resulting strings with a separator string, e.g. a newline?

Example:

```
pic = np.array([ 'H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d']).reshape(2,5)
```

I want to get:

```
"Hello\nWorld\n"
```

Comment: Is the final `\n'` important?  The usual use of `join` puts the separator between strings, but not at the end.

Comment: It's not important - I can always add it later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not hard to do *outside* of numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pic = np.array([ 'H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d']).reshape(2,5)
>>> pic
array([['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
       ['W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> '\n'.join([''.join(row) for row in pic])
'Hello\nWorld'
```

There is also the [`np.core.defchararray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.chararray.html) module which has "goodies" for working with character arrays -- However, it states that these are merely wrappers around the python builtin and standard library functions so you'll probably not get any real speedup by using them.

Answer (score 8):

You had the right ideas there. Here's a `vectorized NumPythonic` implementation trying to go along those ideas -

```
# Create a separator string of the same rows as input array
separator_str = np.repeat(['\n'], pic.shape[0])[:,None]

# Concatenate these two and convert to string for final output
out = np.concatenate((pic,separator_str),axis=1).tostring()
```

Or a one-liner with `np.column_stack` -

```
np.column_stack((pic,np.repeat(['\n'], pic.shape[0])[:,None])).tostring()
```

Sample run -

```
In [123]: pic
Out[123]: 
array([['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
       ['W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [124]: np.column_stack((pic,np.repeat(['\n'], pic.shape[0])[:,None])).tostring()
Out[124]: 'Hello\nWorld\n'
```

Comment: @user5402 Yeah! I wasn't expecting to have a purely numpythonic solution, but it worked out eventually! :)

Comment: It is interesting.  I'm a bit too lazy to try it out, but I wonder how timings would compare to the other (non-numpy) solutions.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and list comprehension , example -

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: pic = np.array([ 'H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d']).reshape(2,5)

In [3]: pic
Out[3]:
array([['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
       ['W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']],
      dtype='<U1')

In [4]: '\n'.join([''.join(x) for x in pic])
Out[4]: 'Hello\nWorld'
```

If you really need the `\n` at the end, you can concatenate it after joining th strings. Example -

```
In [5]: '\n'.join([''.join(x) for x in pic]) + '\n'
Out[5]: 'Hello\nWorld\n'
```